# How could I perform this column subtraction for "n" columns in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to improve the following code for "n" columns and I have no dice so far.

```
A = runif(1000, -2, 2)
B = data.frame(A, runif(1000, -0.5, 0.5), runif(1000, -0.25, 0.25), runif(1000, -0.1, 0.1), ...)
X[, 1] = B[, 1] - B[, 2]     #   << I am stuck in this steps
X[, 2] = X[, 1] - B[, 3]     #   << I am stuck in this steps
X[, 3] = X[, 2] - B[, 4]     #   << I am stuck in this steps
...
...
...
X[, n] = X[, n-1] - B[, n+1] #   << I am stuck in this steps
W = data.frame(B[, 1], X[,1], ... , X[,n]) 
plot.ts(W, plot.type="multiple")
```

I have already tried using a "for loop", however R does not understand "n-1" and "n+1" index increments.

Comment: Please [edit] to add the code you tried here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would probably help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: It won't be necessary. @josilber's solution worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` with `accumulate=TRUE` to apply a function to each column of a data frame in order, accumulating the result. In this case you want to apply subtraction to each pair of columns.

```
setNames(data.frame(Reduce("-", dat, accumulate=TRUE)), names(dat))
#   x  y   z
# 1 1 -1  -1
# 2 2 -1  -6
# 3 3 -1 -11
```

Data:

```
(dat = data.frame(x=1:3, y=2:4, z=c(0, 5, 10)))
#   x y  z
# 1 1 2  0
# 2 2 3  5
# 3 3 4 10
```